# Methods available in GIS to calculate Relief-Length Ratio

Tags: erosion

Relief-Length Ratio is used in Sediment Delivery Ratio calculations, which in turn is used in soil erosion yield calculations.

Relief-Length Ratio has been described in different ways in the literature

> Relief-Length Ratio is calculated based on the DEM and flow direction grid. The elevation change along the downslope flow path is calculated from the DEM and divided by the distance from the center of the current cell to the center of the next cell along the flow path.
>
> R/L where R is the relief of the watershed. It is defined as the
> difference between the average elevation at the main headwaters and
> the elevation at the basin outlet. L is the maximum length of the
> watershed parallel to the mainstream channel

Is there a standard tool in QGIS, ArcGIS, GRASS, SAGA, etc to calculate Relief-Length Ratio? I couldn't find anything in QGIS with a basic search.

Comment: My first  [hit](https://www.ijera.com/papers/vol9no2/S2/H0902023951.pdf) if I search for *Relief-Length Ratio SAGA* is about an open access document with the title *"Morphometry Analysis Using SAGA GIS: A Case Study of
Watershed – 63 of Narmada River, Gujarat, India."*.